# jquery rateIt with meteor: How do I present many star ratings on the same page?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am using jQuery rateIt with Meteor (https://github.com/dandv/meteor-jquery-rateit), and I would like to have multiple ratings on the same page, for e.g.:

```
Alex ****
Barb *****
Chuck *
Dora ***
```

for this, I would need each  to have a different id, for e.g.

```
Alex <div class="rateit" id="1"></div>
Barb <div class="rateit" id="2"></div>
```

...etc...

How would I get the both the id and the rating in my javascript code? I tried something like:

```
'click .rateit' : function(e) {
      console.log('value:'+$('#add-rating').rateit('value') );
      console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

and other combinations, but I still cannot get the id. Any suggestions? This SO post might be relevant:

[How to use star rating (input) field many times in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088436/how-to-use-star-rating-input-field-many-times-in-a-page)

But, frankly, I didn't understand how to implement the proposed solutions in meteor.

EDIT: Thanks to @PSL and @Barmar for their comments on this. Now, I'm having only one small issue: In order for the rating to get saved to the database (i.e. in order for Metor.call to execute), I have to click the rating TWICE. Any thoughts on how I can fix this? (Code is below)

```
'click .rateit' : function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(".rateit").on('rated', function (event, value) {

            // console.log('id:' + event.target.id);
            // console.log('id:' + this.id);
            // console.log('Rating:' + value)

            thisRating = value;
            Meteor.call('Put rating in DB', {rating: thisRating}, function(error, id) {
                if (error)
                    return alert(error.reason);
                else {
                    // alert('success');
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: WHat is the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/mX8cy/

Comment: Inside the function, `this` is the rating element. See example 11 in the [documentation](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm)

Comment: @PSL: This works like a charm! @Barmar: Your comment was also helpful, and provided another way for me to solve the problem - `this` didn't give me the id, but gave me much other information about the document, enough to solve my issue. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @PSL: just one more issue. The proposed solution (see my update/edit above) now requires that I click on the star rating twice in order for the update/insert of the rating to take place. Any advice on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Put $(".rateit").on('rated', function (event, value) in the template rendered callback instead of a click event to avoid clicking the star rating twice.

Comment: @landland: your advice works - now I need to click only once. Many thanks!